# Mi vista de laravel se demora demasiado en responder, hasta un 2 minutos

Tags: php, laravel, array, mvc

Cuando estaba probando en local, funcionaba todo bien por que no manejaba tantos registros, pero cuando lo probe en la nube se demora hasta un minuto en cargar la vista. Asumo que el problema debe estar a la hora de pasar los datos a la vista o cuando los voy a mostrar. La función que retorna los datos es esta:

```
public function ver_consolidado()
    {   
        //Traer requerimientos con servicios consumos cargados
        $idRequerimientosUnicos = Requerimiento::join('servicios_consumos','servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','=','requerimientos.id')
        ->join('precios_venta_divipola','precios_venta_divipola.idLugar','=','requerimientos.idMunicipio')
        ->select('servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','requerimientos.pax','requerimientos.paxDesayuno','requerimientos.paxAlmuerzo','requerimientos.paxCena','requerimientos.precioNoche','precios_venta_divipola.precioDesayuno','precios_venta_divipola.precioAlmuerzo','precios_venta_divipola.precioCena')
        ->distinct('servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento')
        ->get();

        //Crear array consolidado para pasarlo al la vista 
        $consolidado = [];

        //Inicializar variable para llenar el array
        $i = 0;

        //Iterar por cada requerimiento con servicios consumos cargados
        foreach ($idRequerimientosUnicos as $rq) {

            //Capturar la suma de los alojamientos tomados
            $alojamientosTomados[$i] = ServicioConsumo::where('idRequerimiento','=',$rq->idRequerimiento)
            ->sum('tomoAlojamiento');

            //Capturar la suma de los desayunos tomados
            $desayunosTomados[$i] = ServicioConsumo::where('idRequerimiento','=',$rq->idRequerimiento)
            ->sum('tomoDesayuno');
            //Capturar desayunos no tomados
            $desayunosNoTomados[$i] = $rq->paxDesayuno - $desayunosTomados[$i];

            //Capturar la suma de los almuerzos tomados
            $almuerzosTomados[$i] = ServicioConsumo::where('idRequerimiento','=',$rq->idRequerimiento)
            ->sum('tomoAlmuerzo');
            //Capturar almuerzos no tomados
            $almuerzosNoTomados[$i] = $rq->paxAlmuerzo - $almuerzosTomados[$i];

            //Capturar la suma de las cenas tomadas
            $cenasTomadas[$i] = ServicioConsumo::where('idRequerimiento','=',$rq->idRequerimiento)
            ->sum('tomoCena');
            //Capturar cenas no tomadas
            $cenasNoTomadas[$i] = $rq->paxCena - $cenasTomadas[$i];

            //Capturar alimentacion solicitados
            $alimentacionSolicitados[$i] = $rq->paxDesayuno + $rq->paxAlmuerzo + $rq->paxCena;
            //Capturar alimentación tomados
            $alimentacionTomados[$i] = $desayunosTomados[$i] + $almuerzosTomados[$i] + $cenasTomadas[$i];

            /*//Debugear valores
            echo 'Precio noche: '.$rq->precioNoche.'<br>';
            echo 'Alojamientos solicitados: '.$rq->pax.'<br>';
            echo 'Alojamientos tomados: '.$alojamientosTomados[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Tomo desayunos: '.$desayunosTomados[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Tomo almuerzos: '.$almuerzosTomados[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Tomo cenas: '.$cenasTomadas[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Alimentacion solicitados: '.$alimentacionSolicitados[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Alimentacion tomados: '.$alimentacionTomados[$i].'<br>';
            echo '<br>--------------<br>';*/

            //Traer todos los servicios consumos
            $requerimientos = Requerimiento::join('servicios_consumos','servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','=','requerimientos.id')
            ->join('precios_venta_divipola','precios_venta_divipola.idLugar','=','requerimientos.idMunicipio')
            ->select('servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','servicios_consumos.tomoDesayuno','servicios_consumos.tomoAlmuerzo','servicios_consumos.tomoCena','precios_venta_divipola.precioNoche','precios_venta_divipola.precioDesayuno','precios_venta_divipola.precioAlmuerzo','precios_venta_divipola.precioCena','requerimientos.id', 'requerimientos.pax', 'requerimientos.paxDesayuno', 'requerimientos.paxAlmuerzo', 'requerimientos.paxCena', 'requerimientos.idMunicipio', DB::raw('SUM(servicios_consumos.tomoAlojamiento) AS alojamientosTomados'), DB::raw('SUM(servicios_consumos.tomoDesayuno + servicios_consumos.tomoAlmuerzo + servicios_consumos.tomoCena) AS alimentacionTomados'))
            ->groupBy('requerimientos.id','precios_venta_divipola.id','servicios_consumos.id')
            ->get();

            //$alojamientosTomados = $requerimientos->alojamientosTomados;

            $consolidado[$i]['idRequerimiento'] = $rq->idRequerimiento;
            $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosNoTomados'] = $rq->pax - $alojamientosTomados[$i];
            $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosSolicitados'] = $rq->pax;
            $consolidado[$i]['alimentacionNoTomados'] = $alimentacionSolicitados[$i] - $alimentacionTomados[$i];
            $consolidado[$i]['alimentacionSolicitados'] = $rq->paxDesayuno + $rq->paxAlmuerzo + $rq->paxCena;
            $consolidado[$i]['sobranteAlojamientos'] = $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosNoTomados'] * $rq->precioNoche;
            $consolidado[$i]['sobranteAlimentacion'] = ($desayunosNoTomados[$i] * $rq->precioDesayuno) + ($almuerzosNoTomados[$i] * $rq->precioAlmuerzo) + ($cenasNoTomadas[$i] * $rq->precioCena);

            /*//Debugear mas valores 
            echo 'Desayunos no tomados: '.$desayunosNoTomados[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Precio desayuno: '.$rq->precioDesayuno[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Almuerzos no tomados: '.$almuerzosNoTomados[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Precio almuerzo: '.$rq->precioAlmuerzo[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Cenas no tomadas: '.$cenasNoTomadas[$i].'<br>';
            echo 'Precio cena: '.$rq->precioCena[$i].'<br>';
            echo '<br>--------------<br>';*/
            $i++;
        }

        //print_r($idRequerimientosUnicos);

       /* foreach ($idRequerimientosUnicos as $rq) {
            $consolidado[$i]['idRequerimiento'] = $rq->idRequerimiento;
            $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosNoTomados'] = $rq->pax - $requerimientos->alojamientosTomados;
        }*/

        /*echo '<br>'.$rq->paxDesayuno.'<br>';
        echo '<br>'.$rq->paxAlmuerzo.'<br>';
        echo '<br>'.$rq->paxCena.'<br>';*/
        //var_dump($consolidado);
        //var_dump($requerimientos);
        

        /*return view('consolidado.consolidado')->with([
            'requerimientos' => $requerimientos,
        ]);*/
        return view('consolidado.consolidado')->with([
            'requerimientos' => $requerimientos,
            'consolidado' => $consolidado,
        ]);
    }
```

No tengo muy claro como se manejan los objetos asi que lo que decidi hacer es llenar un array con lso datos del objeto a medida que se recorre un loop y para mostrarlos lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
                             <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-bordered mb-2" id="verConsolidados" style="width: 100%">
                                <thead class="text-center">
                                    <tr class="text-center">
                                        <th>Nro autorización</th>
                                        <th>Alo. solicitados</th>
                                        <th>Alo. no tomados</th>
                                        <th>Ali. solicitados</th>
                                        <th>Ali. no tomados</th>
                                        <th>Valor no consumido Alojamiento</th>
                                        <th>Valor no consumido Alimentacion</th>
                                        <th>Ver detalle</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                        $fmt = new \NumberFormatter('es_CO', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

                                        $cantidadResultados = count($consolidado);
                                    ?>
                                    @for ($i = 0; $i < $cantidadResultados; $i++)
                                        <tr class="text-center">
                                            <td>{{ $consolidado[$i]['idRequerimiento'] }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosSolicitados'] }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosNoTomados'] }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $consolidado[$i]['alimentacionSolicitados'] }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $consolidado[$i]['alimentacionNoTomados'] }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $fmt->formatCurrency(abs($consolidado[$i]['sobranteAlojamientos']), 'COP') }}</td>     
                                            <td>{{ $fmt->formatCurrency(abs($consolidado[$i]['sobranteAlimentacion']), 'COP') }}</td>                                     
                                            <td><i class="bi bi-eye-fill"></i></td>
                                        </tr>     
                                    @endfor                      
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Que podria hacer para que no se demore 2 minutos en cargar mi vista ?

27/10/22

Ya saque todas mis consultas del foreach, ahora solo asigno los valores al array dentro del foreach, igual sigue tardando demasiado. Intente quitar el data tables pensando que era el js, pero no.... . Asi que seguro es el Backend, intentare usar las eloquent relationships como lo indica Pipe, o buscare como controlar cuantos resultados mostrar, para no mostrar todos de golpe, mi codigo quedo de la siguiente manera.

```
 public function ver_consolidado()
    {   
        //Traer los ids de los requerimientos con servicios solicitados y precios de venta
        $requerimientos = ServicioConsumo::join('requerimientos','servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','=','requerimientos.id')
        ->join('divipola','divipola.id','=','requerimientos.idMunicipio')
        ->join('precios_venta_divipola','precios_venta_divipola.idLugar','=','divipola.id')
        ->select('servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','requerimientos.pax','requerimientos.paxDesayuno','requerimientos.paxAlmuerzo','requerimientos.paxCena','precios_venta_divipola.precioNoche','precios_venta_divipola.precioDesayuno','precios_venta_divipola.precioAlmuerzo','precios_venta_divipola.precioCena')
        ->distinct('servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento')
        ->orderBy('idRequerimiento','ASC')
        ->get();

        //AlojamientosTomados
        /*//$cantidadRequerimientos = count($requerimientos);
        $serviciosTomados = ServicioConsumo::join('requerimientos','servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','=','requerimientos.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(servicios_consumos.tomoAlojamiento) AS alojamientosTomados'), DB::raw('SUM(servicios_consumos.tomoDesayuno + servicios_consumos.tomoAlmuerzo + servicios_consumos.tomoCena) AS alimentacionTomados'))
        ->get();

        dump($serviciosTomados);*/
        
        $i = 0;

        //Traer los servicios_consumos
        $serviciosConsumos = ServicioConsumo::orderBy('idRequerimiento','ASC')
        ->get();

        foreach ($requerimientos as $rq) {
            //Capturar Id de los requerimientos
            $consolidado[$i]['idRequerimiento'] = $rq->idRequerimiento;

            //Capturar alojamientos solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosSolicitados'] = $rq->pax;

            //Capturar desayunos solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['desayunosSolicitados'] = $rq->paxDesayuno;
            //Capturar desayunos solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['almuerzosSolicitados'] = $rq->paxAlmuerzo;
            //Capturar desayunos solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['cenasSolicitados'] = $rq->paxCena;
            //Calcular alimentacion solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['alimentacionSolicitados'] = $consolidado[$i]['desayunosSolicitados'] + $consolidado[$i]['almuerzosSolicitados'] + $consolidado[$i]['cenasSolicitados'];

            $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'] = 0;

            foreach($serviciosConsumos as $sc) {
                if($sc->idRequerimiento == $rq->idRequerimiento){
                    //echo 'Es el mismo requerimiento<br>';
                    $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'] = $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'] + $sc->tomoAlojamiento;
                    //echo $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'].'<br>';
                }else{
                   //echo 'Es distinto requerimiento<br>';
                }
            }
            $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosNoTomados'] = $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosSolicitados'] - $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'];
            $i++;
        }

        return view('consolidado.consolidado')->with([
            'consolidado' => $consolidado,
        ]);
    }
```

NOTA: ESTOY TRABAJANDO CON CERCA DE 800 registros

Comment: Cuando dentro de un bucle pones tantas consultas MySQL denota un falta de optimización de las mismas. Puedes optar por establecer indices a nivel de bases de datos en las columnas que pones en los WHERE (en tu caso poner uno en la columna `idRequerimiento` puede ayudar) o bien puedes optar por hacer una sola consulta fuera del bucle que comprenda todas esas a la vez y dentro del bucle ir agegando los datos filtrados, conseguidos en esa consulta global, en cada caso que sea neceario.  Usa [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/) para analizar las consultas.

Comment: Para esas consultas dentro del bucle puedes usar las relaciones de Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships y con unas pocas consultas puedes obtener todo los datos que necesitas

Comment: Muy bien, lastima que no parece que hayas conseguido ganar velocidad, pero así es más correcta la forma de enfocarlo.  Revisando tu consulta actual, creo que podrías crear los siguientes índices normales en las tablas para mirar de ganar velocidad tambien:  `requerimientos.idMunicipio`, `precios_venta_divipola.idLugar` y `servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento`

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no encontre una solución como tal para el problema de la carga lenta. Asi que decidi no traer todos los registros de golpe, lo que hice fue crear otra vista para mostrar el reporte que queria pero individual. Mi primer metodo quedo asi:

```
 public function ver_consolidado()
    {   
        //Traer los ids de los requerimientos con servicios solicitados y precios de venta
        $requerimientos = Requerimiento::join('servicios_consumos','servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','=','requerimientos.id')
        //->divipola()
        ->join('divipola','divipola.id','=','requerimientos.idMunicipio')
        ->join('precios_venta_divipola','precios_venta_divipola.idLugar','=','divipola.id')
        ->select('servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','requerimientos.pax','requerimientos.paxDesayuno','requerimientos.paxAlmuerzo','requerimientos.paxCena','precios_venta_divipola.precioNoche','precios_venta_divipola.precioDesayuno','precios_venta_divipola.precioAlmuerzo','precios_venta_divipola.precioCena')
        ->distinct('servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento')
        ->orderBy('idRequerimiento','ASC')
        ->get();

        //Cantidad de requerimientos
        $cantidadRequerimientos = count($requerimientos);

        //dump($serviciosTomados);
        //dump($requerimientos);
        
        $i = 0;

        //Traer los servicios_consumos
        $serviciosConsumos = ServicioConsumo::orderBy('idRequerimiento','ASC')
        ->get();

        //Cantidad de servicios consumos cargados
        $cantidadServiciosConsumos = count($serviciosConsumos);

        foreach ($requerimientos as $rq) {
            //Capturar Id de los requerimientos
            $consolidado[$i]['idRequerimiento'] = $rq->idRequerimiento;

            //Capturar alojamientos solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosSolicitados'] = $rq->pax;

            //Capturar desayunos solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['desayunosSolicitados'] = $rq->paxDesayuno;
            //Capturar desayunos solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['almuerzosSolicitados'] = $rq->paxAlmuerzo;
            //Capturar desayunos solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['cenasSolicitadas'] = $rq->paxCena;
            //Calcular alimentacion solicitados
            $consolidado[$i]['alimentacionSolicitados'] = $consolidado[$i]['desayunosSolicitados'] + $consolidado[$i]['almuerzosSolicitados'] + $consolidado[$i]['cenasSolicitadas'];
            //
            $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'] = 0;

            /*foreach($serviciosConsumos as $sc) {
                if($sc->idRequerimiento == $rq->idRequerimiento){
                    //echo 'Es el mismo requerimiento<br>';
                    $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'] = $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'] + $sc->tomoAlojamiento;
                    //echo $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'].'<br>';
                }else{
                   //echo 'Es distinto requerimiento<br>';
                }
            }
            $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosNoTomados'] = $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosSolicitados'] - $consolidado[$i]['alojamientosTomados'];*/
            $i++;
        }

        return view('consolidado.consolidado')->with([
            'consolidado' => $consolidado,
        ]);
    }
```

Y cree otra función para ver el individual, recibe como parametro el id del requerimiento sobre el cual queiren ver el reporte. Quedo asi:

```
public function ver_consolidado_por_requerimiento($idRequerimiento) {

        //Capturar requerimiento
        $requerimiento = Requerimiento::join('divipola','divipola.id','=','requerimientos.idMunicipio')
        ->join('precios_venta_divipola','precios_venta_divipola.idLugar','=','divipola.id')
        ->select('requerimientos.id','precios_venta_divipola.precioNoche','requerimientos.fechaCheckin','requerimientos.fechaCheckout','requerimientos.pax')
        ->where('requerimientos.id','=', $idRequerimiento)
        ->get();

        //Calcular dias de hospedaje
        $timestampFechaCheckout = strtotime($requerimiento[0]->fechaCheckout);
        $timestampFechaCheckin = strtotime($requerimiento[0]->fechaCheckin);
        $diferencia = $timestampFechaCheckout - $timestampFechaCheckin;
        $noches = $diferencia / (3600 * 24);
        $dias = $noches + 1;

        //Calcular alojamientos solicitados
        $requerimiento[0]->alojamientosSolicitados = $requerimiento[0]->pax * $dias;

        //Capturar servicios consumidos del requerimiento
        $serviciosConsumos = ServicioConsumo::join('requerimientos','servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','=','requerimientos.id')
        ->join('divipola','divipola.id','=','requerimientos.idMunicipio')
        ->join('precios_venta_divipola','precios_venta_divipola.idLugar','=','divipola.id')
        ->select('servicios_consumos.tomoAlojamiento','servicios_consumos.tomoDesayuno','precios_venta_divipola.precioNoche','precios_venta_divipola.precioDesayuno','precios_venta_divipola.precioAlmuerzo','precios_venta_divipola.precioCena','servicios_consumos.fechaInicio','servicios_consumos.fechaFin')
        ->where('servicios_consumos.idRequerimiento','=',$idRequerimiento)
        ->get();


        //Calcular servicios tomados 
        foreach($serviciosConsumos as $sc){

            //Calcular dias de hospedaje
            $timestampFechaCheckout = strtotime($requerimiento[0]->fechaInicio);
            $timestampFechaCheckin = strtotime($requerimiento[0]->fechaFin);
            $diferencia = $timestampFechaCheckout - $timestampFechaCheckin;
            $noches = $diferencia / (3600 * 24);
            $dias = $noches + 1;
            //Alojamientos tomados 
            $requerimiento[0]->alojamientosTomados = ($requerimiento[0]->alojamientosTomados) + ($sc->tomoAlojamiento * $dias);
        }

        //Calcular alojamientos tomados
        $requerimiento[0]->alojamientosNoTomados = $requerimiento[0]->alojamientosSolicitados - $requerimiento[0]->alojamientosTomados;
        //Calcular valores 
        $requerimiento[0]->valorAlojamientosSolicitados = $requerimiento[0]->alojamientosSolicitados * $requerimiento[0]->precioNoche;

        return view('consolidado.consolidadoPorRequerimiento')->with([
            'requerimiento' => $requerimiento,
        ]);
    }
```